# Why does my dynamic viewdata not get listed in my partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have passed the value from controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Page, string sortcol="ID", string sortorder="ASC", string firstname = "", string lastname = "", string emailaddress = "")
{
     int TotalPages = 0;

        var userlist = ur.GetUsersList(firstname, lastname, emailaddress, Page ?? 1, PageSize,out TotalPages, sortcol, sortorder);

        ViewBag.PageIndex = 1;

        ViewData["TotalPages"] = TotalPages.ToString();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("ListUsers", userlist);
        }
        return View(userlist);
    }
```

And in my parent view:

```
@Html.Partial("ListUsers", Model, ViewData)
```

And in my child view (listusers):

```
@ViewData["TotalPages"]
```

i cannot get the value of Viewdata totalpages. Why is it so?
It always returns zero.

Comment: Did you debug and verfied what's your GetUsersList method is returning for TotalPages?

Comment: yes i did checked it is returning me the TotalPages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case don't use View Data,you should create viewModel:

```
var model = new UsersViewModel
{
    Users = userList;
    TotalPages =TotalPages.ToString();
}
```

and at the end:

```
return View(model);
```

Model class:

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users{ get; set; }
    public int TotalPages{ get; set; }
}
```

It's much more elegant solution.